# UIAlertView with a UIActivityIndicator shows up too late/Threading issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, nsoperation

In my app I have a couple places where I'm calling a web service and retrieving JSON, which is then parsed into arrays of objects. The time-consuming part is definitely the web service call. The behavior I desire is as follows:

1. User selects row of interest
2. On current view, AlertView with ActivtiyIndicator subview added
3. Data loads in new VC
4. New view appears
5. AV indicator gone

My VC's are equipped with `doLoadData` methods that basically load an array of data that is displayed by each VC. For example:

`AnimalViewController` has a button "View Dogs" that when pressed does:

`DogViewController *vc = [[DogViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

[vc release];`

`DogViewController` has property `NSArray *dogs` and method `doLoadDogs`, which takes a while to happen.

Currently I have in the "View Dogs" method:

1. Create an AlertView with an ActivityIndicator
2. Show it
3. Create the VC
4. Push it
5. Hide the AlertView
6. Release and nil it

This seems like it would not be difficult but I've yet to find a simple implementation of this with threading.

Answer (score 1):

If your network call/array creation takes a long time and is on the main thread, then all of this will essentially happen at the same time. When you do things like show an alert view, push a navigation controller, etc., what you're really doing is scheduling these things to happen at the next turn of the run loop. Since your "View Dogs" method essentially blocks until everything is done, the run loop isn't executed again until after everything is needed.

The best solution is to factor out your network loading code and not block your main thread/main event loop. As a quick fix, you could factor out the pieces of your current "View Dogs" method using GCD. As an example (obviously this would need to be updated to your actual requirements/code):

```
- (void)viewDogs:(id)sender
{
  dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
  // create and schedule the alert view
  UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle...]; // your real alert view
  dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{ [alert show]; });
  dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{
    DogViewController* vc = [[DogViewController alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
    dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{ [alert dismissWith...]; [alert release]; });
  });
}
```

Comment: This (above code block) improves things some, but now what happens is: viewDogs called, pause, new screen (with data AND activity indicator) appears, activity indicator goes away, black corners go away. What I want to happen is: viewDogs called, display activity indicator on that screen until loadDogs is finished, then display the new screen

Comment: @jshin47 Yeah, it's not good. The best thing is to factor out your loading code so that it doesn't block and notifies you in some way when it's finished. It's relatively easy to do this using GCD, but you wouldn't want to do it all in one method.

Comment: @JasonCoco Why use dispatch_async instead of performselector on a different thread?

Comment: @OscarGomez You could do either. GCD is the modern way, tho, and I personally prefer it. All the code is then inline and easy to follow. That said, however, I wouldn't set it up this way at all. I'd have the other view controller async-load its own data and notify itself when it's ready, not do that stuff here in the action method.

Comment: What exactly am I factoring out? Just the URL request? The request + parsing? Request + parsing + object creation?